# Fixing the size of watermark in all the Picture Sizes Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to place a watermark in all the images captured by my camera. The problem is the picture sizes are different for front and back camera. So, the watermark is coming of different size. Like in back camera, watermark is coming a little smaller and in front camera, as the picture size is smaller than the rear camera, the watermark is coming a little bigger. How can I set the watermark to be of same size in all the pictures.

Here is my code:

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements Callback,
            OnClickListener {

        private SurfaceView surfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private Camera camera;
        private Button flipCamera;
        private Button flashCameraButton;
        private Button captureImage;
        private int cameraId;
        private boolean flashmode = false;
        private int rotation;
        public  static int i=0;
        ArrayList<File> captured_image;
        List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
       public static Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
        MeasureSize measureSize;
        public static Camera.Size size;
        public static int state=0;


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            i=0;
            captured_image.clear();
            captureImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
          releaseCamera();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera);
            // camera surface view created
            cameraId = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
            flipCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flipCamera);
            flashCameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flash);
            captureImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureImage);
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            captured_image = new ArrayList<>();
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            flipCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
            captureImage.setOnClickListener(this);
            flashCameraButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
                flipCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (!getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                flashCameraButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (!openCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)) {
                alertCameraDialog();
            }

        }
        private boolean openCamera(int id) {

            boolean result = false;
            cameraId = id;
            releaseCamera();
            try {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (camera != null) {
                try {
                    setUpCamera(camera);
                    camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {

                        }
                    });
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    result = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result = false;
                    releaseCamera();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void setUpCamera(Camera c)
        {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

            rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int degree = 0;
            switch (rotation)
            {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    degree = 0;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    degree = 90;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    degree = 180;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    degree = 270;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            {
                // frontFacing
                rotation = (info.orientation + degree) % 330;
                rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
            }
            else
            {
                // Back-facing
                rotation = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
            }
            c.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);

            mSupportedPreviewSizes = c.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();


            Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();



            measureSize = new MeasureSize(this);

            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
                    Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
            {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            }


            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            size = sizes.get(0);

                 for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
                 if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width) {
                        size = sizes.get(i);

                    }

                }

                parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

            }


            c.setParameters(parameters);


            Parameters params = c.getParameters();

            showFlashButton(params);

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
            if (focusModes != null)
            {
                if (focusModes
                        .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                }
            }

            params.setRotation(rotation);
        }


        private void showFlashButton(Parameters params) {
            boolean showFlash = (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) && params.getFlashMode() != null)
                    && params.getSupportedFlashModes() != null
                    && params.getSupportedFocusModes().size() > 1;

            flashCameraButton.setVisibility(showFlash ? View.VISIBLE
                    : View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        private void releaseCamera() {
            try {
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    camera.setErrorCallback(null);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
                camera = null;
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                   int height)
        {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                camera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();


                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Activity", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.flash:
                    flashOnButton();
                    break;
                case R.id.flipCamera:
                    flipCamera();
                    break;
                case R.id.captureImage:
                    takeImage();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void takeImage() {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                private File imageFile;

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    try {
                        // convert byte array into bitmap
                        Bitmap loadedImage = null;
                        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
                        loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                data.length);
                         Log.e("Activity", "IMAGE " + data.length);
                        // rotate Image

                        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                        rotateMatrix.postRotate(rotation);
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,
                                loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),
                                rotateMatrix, false);



                            int w = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                            int h = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();
                         //cropped bitmap


                            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, rotatedBitmap.getConfig());
                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                     Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watermark2);
                      float hh = waterMark.getHeight();
                      float ww = waterMark.getWidth();
                     canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, w - ww, h - hh, null);
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        File folder = null;
                        if (state.contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                            folder = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures");
                        } else {
                            folder = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures");
                        }

                        boolean success = true;
                        if (!folder.exists()) {
                            success = folder.mkdirs();
                        }
                        if (success) {
                            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                            imageFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()
                                    + File.separator
                                    + new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString()
                                    + "Image.jpg");

                            imageFile.createNewFile();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        // save image into gallery
                        result.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

                        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                        fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
                        fout.close();
                        captured_image.add(imageFile);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                                imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        CameraActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(
                                Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {

                        i++;
                        if(i<5) {
                            if(i>2) {
                                camera.startPreview();
                                creategif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                camera.startPreview();

                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            captureImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,"You can't take more than 5 pictures", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                }
            });
        }

        private void flipCamera() {
            int id = (cameraId == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK ? CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
                    : CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            if (!openCamera(id)) {
                alertCameraDialog();
            }
        }

        private void alertCameraDialog() {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = createAlert(CameraActivity.this,
                    "Camera info", "error to open camera");
            dialog.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

        private Builder createAlert(Context context, String title, String message) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(context,
                            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
          //  dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            if (title != null)
                dialog.setTitle(title);
            else
                dialog.setTitle("Information");
            dialog.setMessage(message);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            return dialog;

        }

        private void flashOnButton() {
            if (camera != null) {
                try {
                    Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
                    param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
                            : Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(param);
                    flashmode = !flashmode;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }
        }

       public void gallery(View v)
       {
           Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, GIFGallery.class);
           i.putExtra("arraylist", captured_image);
           startActivity(i);
       }
        public void reset_gallery(View v)
        {
                  i=0;
            captured_image.clear();

               captureImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                camera.startPreview();

        }

        public class MeasureSize extends View {
            public MeasureSize(Context context) {
                super(context);

                measure(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());
            }




            @Override
            protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

                if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
                    mPreviewSize =  getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());
                }
            }
        }



        private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            double targetRatio=(double)h / w;
            if (sizes == null) return null;
            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int targetHeight = h;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                double ratio = (double)  size.width / size.height;
                if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }

            if (optimalSize == null) {
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("Activity", "OPTIMAL SIZE " + optimalSize);
            return optimalSize;
        }
    }
```

I tried to make the picturesize same for both front and back camera by setting the parameter equal to previewSize. but it is giving a Runtime exception as the size is invalid:

```
parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the best way to achieve this is to create some sort of scaling algorithm. For example you say that you want the watermark to represent 20 percent of the width and 20 percent of the height. Well if the image is 1000x1000 then you will know that the watermark will be 200x200. This will scale for all different image sizes. Just get the width and height of the image and set a percentage of the width and height you want the watermark to represent.